# Changing text on each page load

Tags: jquery, pageload, dynamic-content, dynamic-text

I'm just starting with jQuery/Javascript and I'm still kind of newbie.

I have a list of phrases and I need them to change inside a `<h4>` everytime the page loads/reloads.

I think this is a basic question, but I can't get the solution (my mind says it's very easy, but my current coding abilities don't).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you need them to rotate one after the other, or is showing a random piece of text enough?

Comment: *inside a h4 tag(...)

Comment: I have a list of phrases and I need to show each one of them everytime the page loads (or reloads).

Comment: Wait - you need to show *each* of them when the page loads? Do you want some sort of rotating ticker like this: http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, try:

```
var textToShow = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h4").html(textToShow[Math.floor(Math.random()*textToShow.length)]);
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZDnv/
Keep clicking 'run' to get different things.

Comment: But if I care about the order, how can I solve this?

Comment: Then you're probably going to need to use cookies.
Drop a cookie to say what number they've just seen, then check for that cookie when the page loads. If it doesn't exist, assume it's -1. Add 1 to that number, and show them `textToShow[cookieNumber]` . Then overwrite the cookie with the new number.